# Regular expression to replace exact matching string

Tags: regex

I want a regex expression to replace any 3 letters in between h1 tags and replace with the same text/letters which exactly matches it along with check tag

For e.g : I have
"[h1] ram [/h1]  
between h1 tags

I need to replace with check tag 
[check][h1] ram[/h1]

Comment: post your attempts. WHy you choose regex for this job?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the starting of the string `^` is followed by your desired pattern in `str` using lookahead so that it doesn't consume text and then replace it with your desired replacement (here `<count>`):

```
import re
str = "<h1>My name is ram</h1>"
reg = '^(?='+str+")"
str = re.sub(reg,'<count>',str)
```

For simple strings like your example don't do this, just prefix the replacement by concatenating as follows:

```
str = '<count>' + str
```